# Group Dates By Weeks Of Quarter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to group weeks into quarters. Quarters are defined:

```
1 Jan - 31MAR
1 APR - 30JUN
1 JUL - 30SEP
1 OCT - 31DEC
```

I have tried using weekOfYear to group which works but I don't know how to then get the start and end of the week from weekOfYear int value.

Below is a list of sample dates. If a week overlaps a quarter I want to cut it short. e.g the last week of the quarter could be 28-30 Jun.

Here is the format I am trying to achieve. Weeks must start from beginning of the quarter:

```
1-7 Jan
8-14 Jan
15-21 Jan
22-28 Jan
29-4 FEB
5-11 FEB
12-18 FEB
19-25 FEB
26-3 MAR
4-10 MAR
11-17 MAR
18-24 MAR
25-31 MAR
```

I am trying to group a list of dates with bill amounts like this:

```
Invoice Issued Date       cost
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 18259.00
2020-01-08 00:00:00.000 35374.00
2020-01-15 00:00:00.000 19793.00
2020-01-22 00:00:00.000 91014.00
2020-02-02 00:00:00.000 23252.00
2020-02-09 00:00:00.000 34628.00
2020-02-16 00:00:00.000 48214.00
2020-02-23 00:00:00.000 9146.00
2020-03-03 00:00:00.000 20234.00
```

If this is easier to achieve in SQL Server I am open to that too.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "quarter".  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @scaisEdge question just got updated

Comment: What day of the week does a quarter start?  The first of this year was Wednesday.  Usually the start of a quart is a start of the week like Sunday or Monday.

Comment: may be SqlFunctions.DatePart can help here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: jdweng it would be easier if that was the case. First day of the year is 1st of Jan. Not a set day of the week

Comment: Check with your accounting department.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this entirely in SQL as follows below.

I have taken the liberty of defining a quarter by taking the month number and dividing by 4.

```
(DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) / 4) + 1
```

Obviously if this isn't suitable for you then you could replace this with whatever logic you need.

```
-- Table Structure
CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Amount DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Sample Data (1000 rows)
;WITH CTE_1000 AS (
    SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) r
    FROM sys.all_objects
)
INSERT INTO Invoice (Date, Amount)
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, r - 1, '20200101'),
    ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000, 2)
FROM CTE_1000;
GO

-- Aggregate Query
;WITH CTE_Quarters AS (
    SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]) [Year],
        (DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) / 4) + 1 [Quarter],
        [Amount]
    FROM [Invoice]
)
SELECT
    [Year],
    [Quarter],
    SUM([Amount]) [SumAmount]
FROM CTE_Quarters
GROUP BY [Year], [Quarter]
ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter];
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/73778/3

Comment: Thanks Chris. That gives the quarters but I am trying to group by the weeks of the quarter